# Generate a specific DataFrame with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 variables

```py
name = ['John','Seen','Sam','Tom','Lisa']

language = ['python','java','C++','javascript']
```

I want to use pandas to generate a DataFrame in a format similar to the following:

| name | Language |
| --- | --- |
| John | python |
| John | java |
| John | C++ |
| John | javascript |
| Seen | python |
| Seen | java |
| Seen | C++ |
| Seen | javascript |
| Sam | python |
| Sam | java |
| Sam | C++ |
| Sam | javascript |

Thanks

Comment: Please accept the answer if it's solved your issue. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
from  itertools import product

df = pd.DataFrame(product(name,language), columns=['Name','Language'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Knowing that: `nameList = ['John','Seen','Sam','Tom','Lisa']`
and `languageList = ['python','java','C++','javascript']`
you do:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'name':nameList,'language':languageList})
```

Comment: Your method can only form one-to-one data

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

name = ['John','Seen','Sam','Tom','Lisa']
language = ['python','java','C++','javascript']

prod=[]
for i in name:
    for j in language:
        prod.append((i,j))
df=pd.DataFrame(prod, columns=['name','language'])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).